# Cannot create a new Rails App after upgrading to Rails 6.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I wanted to start a new rails project and decided to upgrade my Rails and Ruby versions.
I started by upgrading Rails to 6.1.4 and later upgraded Ruby to 3.0.2
Before creating my new app I decided to check once more the version of Rails running and I had this error:

```
$ rails -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I tried the create new rails app command and had the same error as below;

```
$ rails new tracking-app-api --api --database=postgresql
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/el/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I ran the command `$ gem update --system`  and currently have:

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.2 (2021-07-07 patchlevel 107) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/el/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/el/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/el/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/el/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/el/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/el/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/el/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2
     - /Users/el/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/el/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/bin
     - /Users/el/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@global/bin
     - /Users/el/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin
     - /Users/el/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/el/.rvm/bin
```

But I keep having the same error. I am using `macOS Mojave` version `10.14.5`
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running `gem install bundler`.

Comment: @crodev `gem install bundler` after running and successfully installing the gem gives the same error

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051721/2622934) fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran `gem install rails` and it fixed the issue. This is because I upgraded Rails before upgrading Ruby and as such my `gem file` did not have the `rails gem`. So I think it is advisable to always upgrade Ruby before upgrading Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

Comment: i get this  `Could not locate Gemfile` when I run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`