# i am having a problem in bash as well as in cmd when type rails -v , following show up does not know how to do it correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:245:in` bin_path'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051721/895789)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.