# Installed Rails but Got ERROR: can't find gem railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm now using CentOS 8 and I've installed Ruby, gem and Rails.

However, when I tried to validate version of Rails, I got ERROR: can't find gem railties.

I have no idea how to fix it.

Could anyone do me a favor?

Thanks,
Alex

[image]

Update #1:
Could not locate Gemfile
[image]

Update #2:
When I tried to uninstall rails, I got ERROR: Gem 'rails' is not installed

[image]

Comment: Did you try `rbenv rehash`?

Comment: @mechnicov Yes, I tried rbenv rehash, but nothing changed.

Comment: Something very wrong is going on when you install the Rails gem - it should install 20+ other gems that it depends on and output around 110 lines. I'm at loss to explain why - maybe your gem command is getting a completely broken build? Man in the middle attack? I would try `gem uninstall rails` and then try to install it again with the `--verbose` flag.

Comment: Then whatever you're doing with bundler - stop it. Bundler is not used to install Rails which is installed "system wide" (per Ruby version with Rbenv). When you then generate a Rails app it will create a Gemfile and run bundle install to install the dependencies of *that rails application*.

Comment: Also you should not be running any of these commands as the root user. It's insecure and is just going to create a bunch of headaches down the road because the file permissions will be all messed up.

Comment: can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051721/9446028

Comment: @WALVISK bundler is irrelevant if you don't even manage to install the Rails gem. Its only used after you actually create an app.

Comment: @max really weird that I got "Gem 'rails' is not installed" when I typed "gem uninstall rails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really appriciate help from [@max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max)

Finally, I fixed this problem by simply creating a user for ruby and using it to install Rails.

Boom !!!

Fantastic !!!

[image]

## Instructions

[Install Ruby](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-centos-8/)

[Install Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score -2):

First try to install bundler

`gem install bundler`

then run

`bundle install`

And, if its not work Run

`bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

Comment: Thanks Gokuljayanth. I tried your solution but got another err: Could not locate Gemfile.

Comment: @AlexLiang heads up - this is a not a valid answer. Rails needs to be installed first via the `gem` command so that you can actually generate a rails application and a Gemfile. Then you  use bundler to install the additional dependencies.

Comment: @max thanks for your heads up. Really appriciate it.